# compensate transaction when one of the activities not consume command at the specified time in Mass Transit

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit, distributed-transactions, saga

i'm trying to create distributed transaction between multi services. for this cause i'm using mass transit framework - courier feature and RabbitMQ. and my Routing slip config is:

```
public class RoutingSlipPublisher
{
    private readonly IBusControl _bus;

    public RoutingSlipPublisher(IBusControl bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task<Guid> PublishInsertCoding(Coding coding)
    {
        var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());

        builder.AddActivity("Core_Coding_Insert", new Uri($"{RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri}Core_Coding_Insert"));
        builder.AddActivity("Kachar_Coding_Insert", new Uri($"{RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri}Kachar_Coding_Insert"));
        builder.AddActivity("Rahavard_Coding_Insert", new Uri($"{RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri}Rahavard_Coding_Insert"));
        builder.SetVariables(coding);
        var routingSlip = builder.Build();
        await _bus.Execute(routingSlip);
        return routingSlip.TrackingNumber;
    }
}
```

**Issue:**
when *Kachar_Coding_Insert* consumer not connected to RabbitMQ over specified time, I want compensate transaction. but this does not happen and the transaction is not complete until *Kachar_Coding_Insert* consumer connect to RabbitMQ and execute activity.
**How do you solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no centralized orchestrated with Courier, the routing slip is the source of truth. If the routing slip is in a queue waiting to be executed by an activity, and that activity is not available, the routing slip will stay in that queue until the service is started.

There isn't any way to change this behavior, your routing slip activity services should be available. You may want to monitor your services to ensure they're running, it seems like a required activity service not being available would be an unhealthy condition.